# ruby google api client, service account and Google app to use google drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-api-client

You can skip to the problem below but in short I can auth, upload and get a file list but it doesn't correspond to the gmail account I setup with the service account and google dev console

**longer version:**
I created a new email account say blah@gmail.com and used the google development console to enable drive, contacts and a few other APIs for my project.

Then I created the service account API keys/secrets and downloaded the client_secrets.json as well.

It took a while but got authentication working with the ruby google-api-client and I can login via rails console.

**Problem:**
I'm getting file.list but it only has the Getting Started.pdf even though I've created a few docs and spreadsheets on the blah@gmail.com service account.

I can also upload a file but don't see it.

I "think" that it's uploading to Google Apps related account? but I have neither set one up nor do I own domain for the organization I'm setting this up with.

I have no idea where the files are going or uploading or how I can access the drive account I actually did setup with blah@gmail.com

what's going on .

**EDIT:**

Can i get some code example on how to modify this to impersonate user?

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2

@drive = Drive::DriveService.new


scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
@drive.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default([scope])

#give me list of files
@files = @drive.list_files
puts "Search results:"
@files.items.each do |file|
  puts "- File: #{file.title} (#{file.id})"
end
```

If I have to setup google apps this might be tough since they only have subdomains and I don't have direct access. The type of thing I wish I had been told up front.

Comment: Once you register in developers console for service account, you get email address like XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com. To add files into your drive using service account, you need to impersonate the email address of the user by instantiating drive service. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: But I need a Google Apps account or can I just use the blah@gmail.com account and service account. Also from what I've seen the drive site is for pre 0.90 drive ?

Comment: You should have Google Apps account

Comment: Still having issues with client. I edited and added code example. any sample "impersonation" using above code would be very helpful. Thanks again for the tips.